# My script is not working after I convert mysql to pdo

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

```
    <?php

    session_start();

    if (!isset($_SESSION['SESSION']))
        require ("session_init.php");

    // reset session variables...
    $_SESSION['LOGIN_TYPE'] = "";
    $_SESSION['USERNAME'] = "";
    $_SESSION['LOGGEDIN'] = false;
    $_SESSION['FNAME'] = "";
    $_SESSION['LNAME'] = "";

    // initialize variables...
    $username = "";
    $password = "";
    $email = "";

    // make sure post parameters were sent...
    if (isset($_REQUEST["username"]))
        $username = $_REQUEST["username"];
    if (isset($_REQUEST["password"]))
        $password = $_REQUEST["password"];

    // form variables must have something in them...
    if ($username == "" || $password == "") {
        header("Location: ../index.php?flg=red&username=" . $username);
        exit;
    }

   // check in database...
$query = "SELECT * FROM user, position WHERE user.positionID = position.positionID AND logonName = ?";
$result = $connect->prepare($query);
$result->execute(array($username));
```

Error:

> Error line  $result = $connect->prepare($query);
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: connect in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\CAD3\scripts\loggedin.php on line 46
>
> Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on null in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\CAD3\scripts\loggedin.php on line 46

Comment: error is in this line

`$result = $connect->prepare($query);`

Comment: thanks it's my first time here

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: connect in C:\xampp\htdocs\CAD3\scripts\loggedin.php on line 46

Comment: Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\CAD3\scripts\loggedin.php on line 46

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40693513/4982088) and than use `$stmt = $dbh->prepare(...)` and `$result = $stmt->execute(...)`.

Comment: Maybe your connection failed. Better check that.

Comment: The problem is not with SQL, the problem is your `$connect` variable is undefined.

Comment: do you know where is the error exactly ?

Answer (score 0):

Your error is that `$connect` is undefined so you need to create this as

```
$connect = new PDO('mysql:host=HOST;dbname=DBNAME', 'DBUSER', 'DBPASS');
$query = "SELECT * FROM user, position WHERE user.positionID = position.positionID AND logonName = ?";
$result = $connect->prepare($query);
$result->execute(array($username));
```

now replace `HOST, DBNAME, DBUSER` and `DBPASS` with your own information.

Read more about PDO at http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.construct.php

PS: I haven't tested the code above